# Change position of attributed title in button

Tags: swift, button, uibutton, interface-builder

[image: button]

As you see, I want the title is under the image and the both of them center horizontally. Be careful, they are components of a button. I tried changing inset value on interface builder but it didn't work with others screen (I use auto layout), it messed up.

[image]

Can I do it by using IB or have to "hard code"

Comment: You want button title under button image ?

Comment: Yes! Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in interface builder it is easy, just add a button change it to type custom like below image and also title as settings

[image]

and set the image for your button, i set it as `settingsButton.png`.

[image]

now u need to set alignment for example,

[image]

now u can set the insects for image and title, to set insect for image u select the `edge` for `image` like below image, and adjust the insect

[image]

and for title, now select `edge` for `title` and adjust the insect like below image,

[image]

and now your button looks something like below,

[image]

hope this helps u :)

Comment: thanks for your help! it definitely worked because I used to do it in this way :))). So what I actually want is set alignment for them without setting the insects, that's why I added the second image in my question.

Comment: forgive me! I made you confused because I'm not good at English

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a CAShapeLayer to the Button :-

1.) Define a `UIBezierPath` with the `rect :` frame same as that of button

2.) Define a `CAShapeLayer` with path to that of a bezierPath

3.) Add text "B" to the centre of the button by adding a `CATextLayer` : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATextLayer_class/

4.) Add that shapeLayer and textLayer as subLayer to the layer of button, give those layer a respective `zPosition` in this case -1

5.) Set opacity(alpha) for the first layer i.e Button.

Here is what its code might look like : -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupButton()

}

func setupButton(){

    print(btn.bounds)
    print(btn.frame)

    let bezPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: btn.bounds)
    let lyr : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let txtLyr : CATextLayer = CATextLayer()
    lyr.path = bezPath.CGPath
    lyr.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    lyr.zPosition = -1
    lyr.opacity = 0.5
    txtLyr.string = "B"
    //        txtLyr.font = 
    txtLyr.fontSize = 38.0
    txtLyr.zPosition = -1
    txtLyr.frame = btn.bounds
    print(txtLyr.frame)
    txtLyr.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    btn.layer.addSublayer(lyr)
    btn.layer.addSublayer(txtLyr)
}


@IBAction func btnAction(sender: UIButton) {

     print("Button is pressed!")

  }
}
```

With this being the Output : - [image: Simulator Screen]

PS: 1.) In your case only `CATextLayer` would be needed...

2.) That red circle thing that you see in the button is an image.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Do you know how to do it with interface builder?

Comment: What you are asking here is actually a 3D design which to as far as my knowledge goes can only be achieved by code not interface builder .Please accept the answer if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Yes, it definitely worked :)). Don't worry! I appreciated it