# How to replace the button's image and title in storyboard without offset?

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard, interface-builder

Before asking the question, I have searched the relate question in `stackoverflow`, there is a link but not apply me:
[Change position of attributed title in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852820/change-position-of-attributed-title-in-button)

My require is this:

But in my `storyboard`:

How can I replace the `image` and `title`'s position in `storyboard`?
I have tried using `Alignment` and `Insets`, `Insets` can change the position but there will have an issue like below photo:

**EDIT:**

by the way, I tried the set `insets` to title and image, but the result is like this, The title and image did not align to right:

If I set the `insets` of `title` lowly, as you see the `image` is under the title, and set the `image`'s `insets` will not work with role. The `image` is under the character `a`:

Comment: why not use `right detail` style table viewcell? `right detail cell` is what you need. if you still need to create a button, the you can't set the image directly, you must create a UIView, and add image/label to simulate the button. you can't change the image position I think...

Comment: @Enix thanks your advice, but I will look for is there a method to change the position, if there is not , I only can change my initial way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this layout by this insets.

**Xcode 8.0 or Upper**

[image]

**Lower than Xcode 8.0**

[image]

[image]

Comment: seems these insets are only available in Xcode 8+ , right?

Comment: you can set this by Xcode 7 also. But lay out is different.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya thanks, I have edited my question, there is a issue there

Comment: @aircraft problem is solved? If yes, then accept this answer as correct ans.

Comment: @Pramod Tapaniya I am sorry, man, I have tried the answer, but there is also a issue here, please see my EDIT

Comment: @Pramod Tapaniya Before I edit my question, I have tried the left and right `aligment`, and the `image`'s most right position is in the photo I post in my `EDIT`, it will not goto right much more, and you can test in your demo.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Right Detail` style `UITableViewCell`

and also select `Disclosure Indicator` from Accessory of `UITableViewCell`